# categories from prestashop theme aren't displaying the correct names

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

I recently bought a prestashop theme. The theme is great but I have a problem. I've created the categories and they are displayed on the left column but on the top are displayed different names. I just can't find those names and I don't know what to do. here is a print screen:[image]

Those aren't my categories but I don't know from where I can change this.

Comment: Maybe it's a list of "suppliers" or most probably "Manufacturers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this simple method

Open `phpMyAdmin` and search in all the tables of the shop database like this

Words or values to search for: `%YAMAHA%` and then `Select All` tables and search

The table names are easy to read and understand, for example if you found a value in `ps_manufacturer` then you should check `Catalogue` > `Manufacturers` etc ...

Also try using the BackOffice search function although I tried on my demo and it turned nothing when I searched for a Manufaturer that's already added

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these are the names of Manufacturers,
You would use the live edit (Modules > positions > Live edit ) to know which module displays this list of names, then check the configuration of the module if its categories or manufacturers)